# Retrieve Google Analytics quotas consumption via API

Tags: google-api, google-analytics-api, google-developers-console

i want to be able to fetch all the quotas status related to the google analytics API consumption. One part of it seems to be available via IAM:

[image: IAM Quota monitoring console]

First, accessing to these data through an API would be nice..is it possible with the IAM API ?? If so, can i get a sample ?

Next, i need one more data: the google analytics quota consumption PER VIEW (which is limited to 10.000 queries per view per day)..is it also possible to fetch this data, one way or another ?

Cheers,

Clément.

Comment: No there is no way to fetch API consumption data. You may want to keep count of requests made to API in database or something. Daily quotas are refreshed at midnight PST.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At this time there is no way to programmatically access the quota usage of any Google API.

You will either need to check it manually on the google developer website or you will have to keep a count yourself in your application.

There is no other way of fetching data the Google Analytics data. If you have a 360 account you can have your data extracted into Big Query.

You can only make 10000 requests per view per day.  There is also no way to increase this quota.

IAM API is for use with Google cloud and not discovery APIs so no that is not going to help you either.